# Node.js url.parse and Query Strings Behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

Given the URLs:

1. http://somedomain.com/?s=something
2. http://somedomain.com/?s=
3. http://somedomain.com/

Passing through the code:

```
var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
if (queryData["s"]) {
    console.log("s present in hash");
} else {
    console.log("s NOT present in hash");
}
```

I would expect URLs 1 and 2 to test true. They do in other langs/libs I have used before. In querystring parsing code they do not treat #2 as { "s" : null } it just doesn't put s in the hash.
Is there another node package I should use if I want this behavior or another way I should be able to test for s var in the querystring?

Comment: how about `if (queryData["s"] && queryData["s"].length > 0) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `s` **is** in the hash.  It's equal to an empty string, which is exactly what you have in your URL.  When coerced into a boolean, it will evaluate as `false`.

```
> url.parse('http://somedomain.com?s=', true).query
{ s: '' }

> !!url.parse('http://somedomain.com?s=', true).query.s
false
```